# Trying to test a function but in test it returns None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I Have this function that I wish to test, this is how it looks like.

```
def myfunction():
        response = requests.post(url,params=params,headers=headers,data=data)
        response = response.json()
        return response["Findme"].lower()
```

My test script:

```
@mock.patch('requests.post',return_value="{'Findme': 'test'}")
def test_myfunction(mocked_post):
    **assert myfunction() == "test"**
```

When i run the test, i keep getting None for myfunction(), but when i remove the response.json() it works?

Please can anyone assist me.

Comment: You'll need to find another way to mock/test this function. Your mocked `requests.post` returns a string which does not have a `json` method, so I believe `mocking` opted to return `None` instead of raising an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Deep Space, your returned object does not have a `json` method, as it is of type `str`. If you want to have the same behavior as in the tested function, you have to provide an object with that method:

```py
class MockResponse:
    """Mocks relevant part of requests.Response"""
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.json_string = s

    def json(self):
        return json.loads(self.json_string)


@mock.patch("requests.post", return_value=MockResponse('{"Findme": "test"}'))
def test_myfunction(mocked_post):
    assert myfunction() == "test"
```

This way, an object of type `MockResponse` is returned from the mocked `post` function, that can be deserialized using `json()`.

You could also mock the return value of `json` directly instead of mocking the return value of `post`, if you want to do this. In this case you wouldn't need an extra class:

```py
@mock.patch("requests.post")
def test_myfunction(mocked_post):
    mocked_post.return_value.json.return_value = {"Findme": "test"}
    assert myfunction() == "test"
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without class?

Comment: I added a possibility to do this.